# Adding data in fabcar.js

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have added a custom json ( say for ex: students details instead of cars) inside fabcar.js but when i ran ./startFabric.sh node i still able to see the old data gets loaded into the channel .
Any suggestions would be a great help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have just restarted the channel and it got worked me !. kudos